# Web Application HTML messed up on mobile

Tags: mobile, web, meteor

Developed a web application using MeteorJS and deployed it on the MeteorJS cloud. It works great when using a computer however, everything looks very big when attempting to access it through mobile devices.

I don't have much experience with making web applications compatible on mobile devices but I'm just a little lost on what exactly I will need to do. Please advise.

Git: https://github.com/jalapagos/SimpleCalorieCounter

Comment: The link in your readme appears to be broken, it says there's no site deployed at that address. Can you double check?

Comment: Yeah, its working now. Try accessing it via mobile device and you can see how the application breaks down.

Comment: Deployed URL still appears to be broken (still getting the no site deployed address). That said, I cloned it and had a look - there doesn't appear to be any responsive code in the markup/CSS. You need to look at Bootstrap's guides linked below and use the appropriate container/grid system for what you're trying to achieve, Meteor does not automatically make anything mobile responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your app live, it looks like you haven't used any [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) classes for your layout and some of the page elements.

I recommend that you use the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to make you app responsive. A very handy tool for checking how things look in different devices is the Google Chrome Dev tools **device mode**. Here is what your app looks like in an iPad Mini device emulator.

[image]

**EDIT: Added step by step instructions to get started with bootstrap**

Here is what you need to do:

1. Adapt the [basic bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) template for you app. Be sure to include the three `<meta>` tags right after the opening of the `<head>` tag. See @jeremeyK's answer below.

**Note:** the inclusion of bootstrap relates CSS and JS files, or even your custom `caloriecounter.css` file in this main template is **NOT** necessary, since Meteor would do that for you. You have the package `twbs:bootstrap` which will include the bootstrap related files for you.

2. See how the [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) system works. Basically you might want to consider a simple layout like as follows:

[image]

The text in red are the bootstrap class that you need to add to get the layout. You can see that the top navigation bar has a class [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), while the smaller section/sidebar has `col-xs-12` and `col-md-3` classes, and larger section has `col-xs-12` and `col-md-9` classes. The `col-xs-*` applies for very small screen devices while the `col-md-*` applies for medium screen sizes.

What these classes mean here is, for the small section if the screen is very small (xs) then the area should cover the entire width of the window. If the screen is medium sized, then let it just occupy 1/4th of the window to make some space for the table section.

3. Once you have your basic layout ready, go to each component of your app like the [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), [buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons), [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), etc. and fix the HTML markups as per the sample code given for each component.

You can do these things very easily, you only need to follow the guides in the documentation. Also read explanation by @adamwolf below.

Comment: How would you advise to figure out the grid system layout after I've already made my application? I haven't used the grid system layout before so I'm a little confused on how to approach it especially since I've already constructed my application.

Comment: @halapgos1 Please see the edited section for a step by step, to figure out how to use the bootstrap grid system, there is no better place than the official documentation which I've provided links to. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you added a viewport meta tag?](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, cant comment yet. To add to tsega. bootstrap is very easy, just add the class and bootstrap does it for you. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

The grid system is based on 12 columns, by adding the class, for each row you should have the column add up to 12. You can chain these together, for example class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"
this is saying, on a small screen the element width should be 100%, on a medium screen the element should be 50% and on a large screen the element should be 25%.